# Local Cache is not being able to create XML document because the document is too lare

Tags: c#, xml, caching, windows-8, windows-8.1

I am currently developing a Windows 8.1 Application using C# and XAML in which I store a huge amount of data using XML format in the local cache of the application. I am getting the following error with one of the XML files out of three since the other two are being created: "Error:There was an error generating the XML document." Below is my code:

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(localData2))
            {
                StorageFile localFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
                    .CreateFileAsync("LocalCache2.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(localFile,
                    ObjectSerializer<ObservableCollection<aceapp.Competitor>>.ToXml(cacheXML2));
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(localData3))
            {
                StorageFile localFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
                    .CreateFileAsync("LocalCache3.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(localFile,
                    ObjectSerializer<ObservableCollection<aceapp.Attributes>>.ToXml(cacheXML3));
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(localData))
            {
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                StorageFile localFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
                    .CreateFileAsync("LocalCache1.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(localFile,
                    ObjectSerializer<ObservableCollection<aceapp.Sector>>.ToXml(cacheXML1));
            }
```

The Error is with the last XML which is the largest one.
Any idea about this issue and how to fix it?

Comment: does your ram get filled up? Check in the task manager, you should use a difrent solution then if you are dealing with such huge amounts of data. Read it from the disk in batches or something along those lines